# Help with a stacked cluster graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to compare the weight and volume of two power options. One consist of FC, battery and motor and the other consists of 4-stroke engines

i edit the following code but it doesn't give me the required output

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[ybar stacked,bar shift=7pt,ymin=0,ymax=30,symbolic x coords={Wight,Volume}]]  

\addplot coordinates
{(Weight,0.375) (Volume,0.66)};

\addplot coordinates
{(Weight,8.885) (Volume,4.44)};

\addplot coordinates
{(Weight,5.4) (Volume,16.16)};

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[ybar stacked,bar shift=-7pt,ymin=0,ymax=30,symbolic x coords={Wight,Volume}]  

\addplot [fill=blue!50!gray] coordinates
{(Weight,13.064) (Volume,28.424)};

\legend{FC,Battery,Motor,4-stroke}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

The output is as shown

[image]

I don't want this big space and axis is written in Bold because it is double written as i think and the legends as well

Comment: Can you please complete your code so it will compile? Something people can copy-paste-compile to see the problem.